# double value changed when printf() C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, double

I'm trying to learn about pointer, and I got a task, but when I tried to print a float array, the 1st value changed.

```
void getinputA(double *aa){
    while(1){
        scanf("%lf", &*aa);
        getchar();
        if(*aa< 100 || *aa>10000){
            printf("input the right amount\n")
        }else{
            printf("success\n\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    return;
}

void getinputB(double *bb){
    while(1){
        scanf("%lf", &*bb);
        getchar();
        if(*ten == 1 || *ten == 3 || *ten == 6 || *ten == 12){
            printf("success\n\n")
        }else{
            printf("input the right number\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    return;
}


void getinputC(double *cc){
    while(1){
        scanf("%lf", &*cc);
        getchar();
        if(*cc<1 || *aa>10){
            printf("input the right number\n")
        }else{
            printf("success\n\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    return;
}


int main(){
    double A;
    int B, C, Rep, D;
    getinputA(&A);
    
    Rep = (12/B)*C
    
    
    

    
    for(int i=0; i<Rep; i++){
        if(i == 0){
            D[i] = A;
            //checked, still correct
        }else{
            D[i] = AnotherVarInMyCode[i-1];
            //checked, still correct
        }
        AnotherVar[i] = A[i]*(DifferentVar/(12/B));
        AnotherVarInMyCode[i] = A[i]+AnotherVar[i];
    }
    
    
    AFunction();
    //here
    
    for(int i=0; i<Rep; i++){
        printf("%d %.2lf\n", i+1, D[i]);
        //when I input 1000, it prints -400, and when I input 100, it -0,98
    }
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

I found out that the value change after it runs a function which I don't use D, why does this happen? And how to fix it?

I've checked my code, but I can't figure out why it changed.

if changed from 1000 to -200, and from 100 to -0.98

Comment: "I found out that the value change after it runs a function which I don't use D" How? What are the observed symptoms?

Comment: Your example seems to be missing some important bits. When you fix that also include the input you're using and the expected output.

Comment: I don't get `void getinputC(*cc)`. What do you mean by it and what is your compiler yelling about it at you? The way you use it if should be `void getinputC(double *cc)`.

Comment: `&*aa` This is exactly the same as `aa`.

Comment: this code is missing too much stuff to be understood

Comment: Rep = (12/B)*C - UB as you do not initialize B & C

Comment: basically, you should write it again from the beginning. Use proper formatting, meaningful variable names etc etc

Comment: Your code does not compile. Therefore it cannot run and therefore your question is pretty strange. Please [edit] and post a [mcve]

Comment: Compile with the `-Wall` flag, fix all warnings. They are important. Heck, on what kind of platform did you even turn this into an executable? gcc fails with a load of errors.